# How to get columns corresponding to n largest values in a single row dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I've a dataframe like this

```
    c0   c1   c2   c3   c4   c5
0   2    4    3    1    6    5
```

and would like to get the columns corresponding to the `n` largest values in the single row e.g. with `n=3`

```
    c4   c5   c1
0   6    5    4
```

How can I achieve this most efficient (w.r.t. memory usage, execution time and ability to parallelize with dask)?

As reference w.r.t. performance the answer of @stark (dataframe with 500 cols, n=10): With `df.sort_values(0, axis='columns', ascending=False).iloc[:, :n]` I get `649 µs` with `%%timeit`.

Comment: Sort and slice.

Comment: @stark That's what I'm trying right now...

Comment: There is multiple rows? what is expected output if more rows?

Comment: In this particular case I've just one row.

Comment: @stark If you add the comment as answer I'd accept it as fastest (given that no further performance comparison has been done depsite of simple timeit, no parallelization, etc.).

Comment: Added as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the 3 highest values (for example), just sort and slice:

```
df.sort_values(0, axis='columns', ascending=False).iloc[:, :n]
```

Comment: W.r.t. performance: Dataframe with 500 cols, n=10 with  `%%timeit` I get `649 µs`. I don't know about how good it scales right now. So far fasted implementation.

Answer (score 3):

Use `numpy` - [`np.argsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) for positions of sorted values, get first `3 values` use and `iloc` for select:

```
df = df.iloc[:, np.argsort(-df.values[0])[:3]]
print (df)
   c4  c5  c1
0   6   5   4
```

Comment: Cause I've just one row in this case there is no way to parallelize, right? Using numpy seems to be most performant then...

Comment: @thinwybk - My main problem is not understand goal, so no idea

Comment: With dataframes you can usually parallize w.r.t. columns (groupby) or by processing rows in parallel. However this depends on the actual problem which needs to be solved. In this case there is just 1 row, no way to parallize w.r.t. rows. But columns could be potentially processed in a parallel way. Split columns in to groups, find n largest, reduce to overall n largest w.r.t. all columns.

Comment: On my machine with `%%timeit` I get with approx. 500 columns `8ms` execution time.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
# return the n columns with maximum value
def n_max_row(df, n):
    return df.apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(n).index.tolist(), axis=1)
```

In your case, where you have this DataFrame:

```
#     c0   c1   c2   c3   c4   c5
# 0   2    4    3    1    6    5
```

It would typically give you:

```
print(n_max_row(df, 3))

# > 0    [c4, c5, c1]
```

Now, the good point is that if your DataFrame contains multiple rows, it will return a list with each element being the three columns for which the corresponding observation has the highest value.

For instance, if your DataFrame `df` is as such:

```
#    A  B  C  D
# 0  3  5  1  2
# 1  2  4  7  1
```

Then, the output would be:

```
print(n_max_row(df, 3))

# > 0    [B, A, D]
# > 1    [C, B, A]
```

---

Execution times for a DataFrame with one row and `n` columns are as follows :

- `n = 10`: 2.32 ms ± 232 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
- `n = 100`: 2.82 ms ± 398 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
- `n = 1000`: 8.66 ms ± 340 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
- `n = 10000`: 66 ms ± 2.85 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

Comment: Could you add rough execution time pls?

Comment: W.r.t. my reference implmentation slower: `6.17 ms`

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1**

```
new_df=df.T.nlargest(3,df.index.tolist()).T
print(new_df)

   c4  c5  c1
0   6   5   4
```

---

**Time**

```
%%timeit
new_df=df.T.nlargest(3,df.index.tolist()).T
1.6 ms ± 305 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

---

**Method 2**

```
df.iloc[0].nlargest(3)
c4    6
c5    5
c1    4
Name: 0, dtype: int64
```

if you want a dataframe:

```
new_df_0=df.iloc[0].nlargest(3).to_frame().T
print(new_df_0)

   c4  c5  c1
0   6   5   4
```

---

**this is fater:**

```
%%timeit
new_df_0=df.iloc[0].nlargest(3).to_frame().T
1.08 ms ± 28.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: Method 1 slower than my reference: `1.92 ms`. Method 2 slower than my reference: `1.92 ms`. Method 2 slower as well: `2.71 ms`.

Comment: this depends on where it runs, so what you should compare are the differences

Comment: I know, but I've run all answers on  my machine given same conditions.

Comment: What has been the best method? you should accept the answer you consider best

Comment: Righ now my reference implmentation is fastest. However I'm not sure about how it scales yet (dependent on column count and n).